# Busting the cache in webpack still requires a soft reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, browser-cache, webpack-4

I recently configured Webpack (version 4) to split the bundle in three chunks (bundle, runtime and vendor) and also to append a hash to the beginning of each of their filenames so that the browser can sense the changes in them. I'm also updating the HTML references with the HtmlWebpackPlugin.

This seems to be working, but not fully, let me explain. Before I did this, a hard reload was needed after each deployment in order to see the new changes, this is no longer needed.

Now the problem is, when you load the web app after a deployment for the first time, it still shows you the old version, it's only when you soft reload the webpage that it shows the new changes.

What I am wondering is, is there any way that I can get rid of this behavior so that whenever a deployment is done and you load the web app the changes instantly show up without the need of refreshing once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "load the web app" you mean open a tab, enter the web app URL and visit it?

Answer (score 0):

You could append a random querystring to the import of your bundles, like `src="bundle.js?nocache=12345"` that's generated everytime.

This prevents the browser from caching your code, and doesn't require you to change the bundle names (which is convenient).

If you don't want it to be loaded fresh each time even when you're not releasing anything, you should keep something like a version number somewhere and append that in a querystring to the bundle import instead.

Though, your current implementation basically does the same. It should be a fresh non-cached bundle when you open the web app.. I don't think there is a way to make the browser detect changes in javascript and refresh the imported scripts, unless you are working with something like `webpack-dev-server` (hot reload) that does that for you, but that's development convenience only.